# Getting React Native errors with Flow

Tags: javascript, react-native, flowtype

I set up Flow and React Native created its default .flowcongif file. But "npm run flow" returns a ton of errors about react native libraries:

```
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/DatePicker/DatePickerIOS.ios.js:38
 38: const DatePickerIOS = React.createClass({
                           ^ call of method `createClass`. Expected a React PropType instead of
371:     hitSlop: EdgeInsetsPropType,
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ object type. See: node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/View/View.js:371

node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/DatePicker/DatePickerIOS.ios.js:105
105:     this.props.onChange && this.props.onChange(event);
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ call of method `onChange`. Function cannot be called on
105:     this.props.onChange && this.props.onChange(event);
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ property `onChange` of unknown type
```

Comment: What makes you think those ignored files are relevant to the errors you see? Even the paths aren't the same!

Comment: Perhaps they are not. I am new to RN. My questions would still be why am I getting these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the right version of Flow?

Check the version at the bottom of the `.flowconfig` file and make sure that's the version you install.

Right now that would be:

> npm --save-dev install flow-bin@0.42.0

Comment: Yes, looks like: [version] ^0.42.0

Comment: Yes but what version did you install?

Comment: At the bottom of flowconfig it says [version] ^0.42.0 and in ackages.json it says "flow-bin": "^0.42.0"

Comment: Your flow versions would seem to be OK. Perhaps an old npm or node? If I init a new RN app, add flow-bin and run flow I do not get any errors (tried it yesterday). I'm using npm v4.5 and node v7.5. Have you tried creating a new blank app?